# Can one say, "John Doe for World Cup," meaning "I vote for John Doe to have a place in the national team"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Or, in the same manner, "John Smith for Olympics" meaning any place in a team, crew, etc?

I know that it's common practice to say "John Doe for president," but here "president" is a profession/title, while "World cup" and "Olympics" aren't.

Comment: Sounds strange. Perhaps John Doe for Olympian :) At least use John Doe for _the_ Olympics

Comment: I agree with mplugjan - you can use **the** for an event and it should be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say (as JoseK already reported in a comment) "John Smith for the Olympics".

Comment: Thanks! I needed something short and catchy and with "the" it really sounds right. Ouch, how could I forget that "the"? :)